# memory addresses are not showing up in eclipse (e2studio) source debug view

Tags: debugging, eclipse-cdt, renesas-rx

I am debugging a C program using e2studio (eclipse) and Renesas Synergy.  I have run into an issue when I am using the source code debugger, that the memory addresses are not showing up in the left column as they should.  It is not about optimization because I get no addresses AT ALL.  Is there some setting, I checked the dropdown when I right-click the column, and select "Show Source Addresses", so it's not that.

My associates don't seem to have this problem with their machines, which makes it even worse.

[image: This is a typical Screen Shot]

Further information: I was able to create a simple hello world program and when I ran THAT, the memory addresses showed up.  So there must be some kind of project setting or debugger setting that is suppressing this.  I can still set breakpoints and single step, which makes it really confusing.

Comment: Do you have a screen shot of the mentioned View?

Comment: @nitind as it is company code, I can't screen shot it unless I can find a good innocuous section of code, or maybe I can just pull up a "hello world" program.  I'll get back and insert it when I get a chance.  But it's really just the source file window in the Debug perspective.

Comment: @nitind Added screen shot.  I also completely uninstalled and reinstalled e2studio.  I guess I'll go get the latest and see if that helps.  I swear the version I have used to work correctly...